# What exactly is the "coherence" between waves?

Tags: waves, definition, coherence

I know, by definition, that [*coherence*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_%28physics%29) means that a pair of waves have constant phase difference. What does this mean?

Does it mean they always have a 360 degrees, or 0 degrees phase difference? Or could they have 40 degrees or *any* constant phase difference?

In order to have constant phase difference must they have the same wavelength and frequency?

Comment: Any constant  phase difference, and they have to have the same frequency. For electromagnetic waves wavelength and frequency are connected through the velocity in the medium.

Comment: There's a fantastic explanation of coherence here: http://amasci.com/miscon/coherenc.html

Comment: @Dave that is a good article on coherence. Thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 7):

Waves can be coherent and yet not have the same wavelength. It is sufficient that they have the same frequency - because that is sufficient to imply a constant phase difference.

If you make a Michelson interferometer where you split an incoming light beam into two arms, and you send half the light through a column of water and the other half through air, then it is possible to get interference between the beams by adjusting the path lengths (according to the refractive index).

It is worth noting that typically waves do not consist of a single pure frequency, and that there will be some small drift in frequency over time. Because of this, if you split light into two branches but make them come back together after they have covered different path lengths, then the interference pattern they will create (a measure of the coherence) will become less.

For this reason, with "monochromatic" light we sometimes talk of the "coherence length" - a measure of how different the path lengths can be before you lose a significant fraction of the coherence (before the interference pattern starts to fade).  As @wbeaty pointed out, it is more proper to call this the *temporal coherence length* (how much earlier or later can you look at the beam and find it is still capable of interference) - but since you are measuring time "along the beam", there is a direct relationship between the coherence time and the length along the beam that the light can interfere.

Comment: Actually, white light can be coherent.  Starlight is coherent, and the entire field of Stellar Interferometry exists. Starlight is far more coherent than laser light: the coherence-length of light from distant stars is measured in hundreds of kilometers.  The light from nearby giant stars (Betelgeuse) is shorter: a few meters, as discovered by Michaelson when founding Stellar Interferometry.   On the other hand, "coherence" usually means spatial coherence, as with laser light being coherent but also monochromatic   ...while "monochromatic" means long temporal-coherence length.  Two concepts.

Comment: @wbeaty - I think we have the same understanding but are using different words. Stellar interferometry allows you to infer the angular extent of a very small source (which has great spatial coherence) by seeing how large a baseline can be used to collect the stellar light and still obtain fringes - see [here](https://www.eso.org/sci/facilities/paranal/telescopes/vlti/tuto/tutorial_introduction_to_stellar_interf.pdf). I was talking about coherence _length_ which is measured along the beam, not perpendicular to it.

Comment: Yes, same understanding  ...but coherence length is not measured as you say, because only *temporal coherence length* is measured along the beam.  High spatial coherence implies very large *spatial coherence length*, which is measured perpendicular to the beam.  Also, in general non-scientific use, the term "coherent light" refers to spatial coherence, while"monochromatic light" refers to temporal coherence.  This is distinct from the "coherence" concept in physical optics.    See also http://amasci.com/miscon/coherenc.html#math

Comment: @wbeaty I either remember wrong, or when I was taught these things in the 80's the terms were used more interchangeably. You measure the temporal coherence by changing the length of one of the arms of the Michelson interferometer; that links what I call "coherence length" (the distance you can move one mirror and still see fringes) with "temporal coherence" but I see how that is confusing and at odds with your link. I will try to mend my ways. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, since jargon varies with field of study (physics versus laser optics versus astronomy, never the triune shall meet!)  It's often difficult to extract meaning from context.  Stellar interferometers move their mirrors across the beam.    I recall yet another version: " longitudinal" coherence-length versus "transverse" coherence-length (corresponding to temporal coherence versus spatial.)

Comment: @Floris Do coherent waves also have same velocity .I have seen during derivation for intensity of constructive and destructive interference ,the wave velocity are taken to be equal

Comment: @magemaro the short answer is “yes”. The long answer is ... long.

Answer (score 4):

Coherence means a constant phase relationship; the phase difference could be anything, such as $\pi$ or $7 \pi / 4$.

Naively, that means that two waves are coherent if and only if they have the same frequency, which makes the idea of coherence sound silly. However, it actually stands in for a lot of real world effects that can destroy interference. For example:

- Light from a fluorescent bulb, which has (roughly) a single frequency, is not coherent. Each atom in the bulb is wiggling independently, so instead of getting one light wave at some frequency, you get a ton of little wavetrains of the same frequency but independent phases, one from each atom.
- Even if you fix the above problem, light *can't* have a definite frequency. Classically, if you look at an EM wave, it satisfies an uncertainty principle of the form $\Delta \omega \Delta t > 1$ for the same Fourier-transform reasons that the usual uncertainty principle holds. Quantumly, if you're considering photon emission, it satisfies the uncertainty principle $\Delta E \Delta t > \hbar$, which gives you the same thing. Since all light contains a range of frequencies, it is impossible to have exactly the same frequency, and the effect is noticeable after some length scale.

The length scales above are called coherence lengths. Above the coherence length, interference patterns start to fade.

Comment: I have a question for your first outline in your example: You say the phases are independent. Why is that? I would have guessed, that (let's take two atoms) if one atoms starts radiating at one time t1 and the second at another time t2, they have a fixed phase to each other. Unless, we assume that along with a different time of emission our waves also have $\phi_{1}=\phi(t_{1})$ and $\phi_{2}=\phi(t_{2})$ to be unequal. The question then, for me, is why are the phases different?

Comment: It's true, every pair of atoms will have a fixed phase relationship. But you don't just get one pair, you get billions, all of which are starting and stopping independently all the time.

Comment: If they weren't starting and stopping all the time, but simply began and continued, such that there were a billion light waves being emitted, each with a constant frequency and thus constant phase differences with respect to the other billion - 1 light waves, would the light bulb's light then be coherent?

Comment: "Naively, that means that two waves are coherent if and only if they have the same frequency" - why naively? Are there cases where the same frequency is insufficient in guaranteeing constant phase difference between the waves?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is exactly so. The same phase difference, wave length and frequency. What is important, but implicit here, is that both waves exist at the same time at the same place. Then they added up and act on a screen or on a probe charge as a sum. Their interference is impossible if they do not act at the same time.